# change sql query using selected text in combobox

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I'm writing a program using MySQL and WinForm. In my program there's an option to select a **VAT Number** from a combobox that is retrieve from a table in database. After selecting a **VAT Number** user have to enter 2 different values into 2 different textbox. After entering those values, the sql query will execute. And show the result in another textbox.

[Application form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMapE.png)

My sql queries are working fine.

```
using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(cs))
{
      con.Open();
      //string command;

      string command = @"SELECT * FROM `db_liq_blnd_calc_sys`.`tbl_vat_12_spirit_sa` WHERE DIP = '" + txt_Calc_BULK_DIP.Text + "' AND SLIDE = '" + txt_Calc_BULK_SLIDE.Text + "'";
      MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command, con);
      DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      da.Fill(ds);
      DataRow[] returnrow = ds.Tables[0].Select("DIP = '" + txt_Calc_BULK_DIP.Text + "' AND SLIDE = '" + txt_Calc_BULK_SLIDE.Text + "'");
      int result = returnrow.Length;
      DataRow dr = returnrow[0];

      txt_Calc_BULK_BULK.Text = (dr["BULK"].ToString());

      con.Close();
}
```

What I wanna do is, there are 15 table in my database that has same table structure but different data in it. I want to change the sql query that execute by selecting different **VAT Number** from the combobox.

Comment: So basically you want to select data from different tables based on the VAT Number?

Comment: Why do you have 15 similar tables in your database?

Comment: YES. By selecting the VAT Number, the sql query most change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all tables have the same structure, I recommend making one big table for them all and add a VAT Number column to it. Then, to set the values in your combobox, select distinct VAT Numbers from this table. Finally, add the a VAT Number condition to your query.

On a side note, use "Parameterized Query" instead of concatenating values to your query, this would help against SQL Injection Attacks.

Comment: But the problem is all the table has to be separated. These tables holds the data of some liquid tanks. There are 15 different tanks. And also 15 different tables. We need to check the current level of liquid in the tank by using the table. We have been doing this process in manual way. Now we decided to make a program to do the whole process.

Comment: Here are some questions. Do the tanks have multiple VAT Numbers? or a single one? Are the VAT numbers unique? or shared between tanks?

Comment: @inD4MNL4T0R this is not really a great excuse. You could add a tank identifier field to the combined table to be able to tell which record applies to which tank.

Comment: @SohaibJundi Yes. all of the tanks have unique VAT Numbers. And also each table contains approximately 2000  records.

Comment: you answered the second question only. What about there number per tank? Is there a single number? or multiple?

Comment: I would replace all these tables with just 2, the first with these columns (BULK_ID, VAT_Number, DIP, SLIDE, BULK) and the second with these columns (VAT_Number, Tank) and have the second table reference the first

Comment: Actually that makes sense. I'll try it. Btw thank you @Sohaib for taking time for help me.